# Search for particular character inside a string

Tags: java, string, text

I have a string .. I need to search for some particular texts inside this string if it is present total numbers need to be returned.
I know how to return a character of particular place

```
String string = "Hi How are you";
b = string.contains("H")  ;
```

But I need to get multiple characters for example..I need to search for 'A' and 'S' inside a string and I need number of times it is coming.

how I will write the code for that.I know how to search in a particular place and search for a particular character. But how for more than i character and return its total number.

```
String string = "Hai How are you!"; 
char aChar = anotherPalindrome.charAt(9);
```

I know it will reeturn 9th place character.

```
String string = "Niagara. O roar again!"; 
String roar = string.substring(5, 7);
```

I know it will return 'How'

Comment: you need to split the string in a characters array and then loop through to match the desired character. Count your variables on every match!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this here three characters AJS can be searched.. if you need to search its small characters give like 'AaJaSs'..

```
String string;
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([AJS])"); //case insensitive
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(String);
 int count = 0;
 while (matcher.find()) count++;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use regular expressions. Android provides the [Pattern class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  to this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Try looping with help of the indexOf() method.

Example:

```
String exampleString = "Hai How are you!";
String searchedString = "H";
int index = exampleString.indexOf(searchedString , 0);
int counter = 0;

while(index != -1) {
    counter++;
    int index = exampleString.indexOf(searchedString , index);
}

System.out.println("The character " + searchedString  + " occurs " + counter + " times.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method to count the frequency of the character in the string :

```
public static int count(char character){
    return str.toUpperCase().split((""+character).toUpperCase()).length - 1;
}
```

Then use this method as shown below:

```
b = string.count('H');
b = string.count('A');
```